# Is there a way to delete certain rows by bundle?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

To make datafram `dataset` into a test set and a train set, I split it to `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test`.

[image]

To get only train set, I think I have to extract only X_train rows or delete X_test rows.
So I typed as below. However, I guess that `X_test_y_test = dataset[dataset['Label']== X_test].index` is problem... How can I get only train set?

[image]

Comment: After `train_test_split`, `X_train`, etc., already has what you need.

Comment: OOps haha You are right. Thank you!